# Validation to force user to fill all two textboxes or neither

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-validators

I have two `TextBox` on my page, and i want when a user fill one of them i warn him to fill another textbox, i mean  to force user to fill all two textboxes or neither. 
How to implement this using Validators, if applicable?

I added this controll on my page

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt1" Enabled="True" ID="required_validator1" runat="server" Text="Required" Visible="True" ValidationGroup="T"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt2" Enabled="True" ID="required_validator2" runat="server" Text="Required" Visible="True" ValidationGroup="T" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" CausesValidation="False" Enabled="False" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="T" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

and in my `Webform.aspx.cs` :

```
  protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt1.Text.Length > 0)
            txt2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

and :

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt1.Text == string.Empty && txt2.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            required_validator1.Enabled = false;
            required_validator2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

i want when user did not write any thing on `txt1` and then he click on button, the validator warning does not show him an let him to resume,but it does not work, how can i do ti?

Comment: Have you tried custom validator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Look into Required Field Validator you can do it easily

Comment: See also [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/756232/49942)

Answer (score 0):

Use the logic. Set `Required Field validator` on both `textboxes`, and `disable` the second textbox. If user enters anything in the 1st `textbox` then **enable** 2nd `textbox`.

You can implement it using javascript. Simply set the textchange event of first textbox and check if its text length is greater than 1 then enable 2nd textbox.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>    
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt1" Enabled="True" ID="required_validator1" runat="server" Text="Required" Visible="True" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" runat="server" />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt2" Enabled="True" ID="required_validator2" runat="server" Text="Required" Visible="True" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" CausesValidation="False" Enabled="False" runat="server" />       
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt1" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txt1.Text.Length > 0)
        txt2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: IS there any way to do it,without javascript?

Comment: You can also do it using `c#` but it will require postback on every textchange. If you want to do it with `c#`, use ajax update panel to async postback on textchange.

Comment: I've guided you all the way. Give it a try, if you get stuck anywhere then ask.

Comment: I do it as you said but it give me error : Could not find an event named 'TextChange' on associated control 'txt1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: That was a typing mistake. Use `TextChanged` instead of `TextChange`.